# Regex select everything up until next match including new lines

Tags: regex, match, newline

Im trying to capture the conversation below but the regex expression only capture a single line, I want it to capture the entire phrase said by anyone up until the next person says anything else. If I use the /s setting, the '.+' will capture everything until the end of the file not until the next match

Im new to the regular expressions, sorry for any bad explanation

This is what Ive got so far

The regex expression:

```
/([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}: (.+):) (.+)/
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyJIw.png)

[Regex101 Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/h49Yq0/1)

I going to use use both \2 and \3 to capture who said and the phrase said inside a for loop so I can text mine it

Comment: Why not share a regex fiddle? Please post the link to your regex101 attempt.

Comment: Instead of adding images to your post, can you create a minimal example with text that people can copy. That would help folks test any answer they provide.

Comment: What language? And please post your examples inline, instead of as images.

Comment: It looks like you're using regex101, which will provide a shareable link of whatever you're working on if you press ctrl+s

Comment: Sorry, should have remembered about the sharing feature

[Regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/h49Yq0/1)

Ill be using c# 
Thanks!

Comment: How can you see the difference between the timestamp and some forging a timestamp in their message ? I'd say you need to change your raw string to something with a delimiter.

Comment: Also, if you want to match any character including new lines, use `[\S\s]` instead of `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pattern to extract, then some LINQ to process:

```
var pattern = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}: (.+?): ((?:[^/]+(?:\n|$))+)";

var data = Regex.Matches(src, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>().Select(m => new { who = m.Groups[1].Value, text = m.Groups[2].Value});
```